# Как добавить/удалить класс диву при наведении курсора на него?

Tags: javascript

Есть див, которому нужно при наведении курсора на него добавить класс,
а при отводе курсора удалить этот класс. Как это можно реализовать на javascript?

Comment: Обязательно ли на JS, если можно ограничиться CSS – см. [псевдокласс `:hover`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover)

Comment: Нужно добавить класс при наведении, а удалить при отводе курсора. Ховер не подходит.

Comment: @Виктор Павлов свойства из этого класса запишите в псевдокласс `myClass:hover`. [Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/oqg090fe/1/). Как-то неправильно писать JS там, где можно обойтись CSS без извращений )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще я согласен с [[@Sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks)](/users/7161/sergiks) по поводу того, что данный вопрос можно легко решить с помощью css, но если хотите всё-таки JS, то вот:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hover-element').hover(
    function() {
      $( this ).removeClass('class-name');
    }, function() {
      $( this ).addClass('class-name');
    }
  );
});
```

Сделано по мотивам [официальной документации](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Answer (score -2):

Или так

```
$('div').mouseover(function(){
$(this).addClass('hover');
});
$('div').mouseleave(function(){
$(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Или так

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div').hover(
        function(){ 
            $(this).find('.div').toggleClass('visible');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Не знаю почему, но так работать не хочет.

Comment: Потому что оба варианта сделаны на jQuery, а автор просил на чистом JS